# Zend vs .NET

Tags: .net, zend-framework, php

Какой фреймворк лучше учить для создания небольших и не очень больших проектов? Опишите все плюсы и минусы, которые Вы видите в asp.net,ado.net и php, а именно zend. Представьте пожалуйста результат сравнения их трудности в обучении и востребованности на рынке.

**Заранее спасибо!**

Comment: у меня один знакомый устраивался в большую компанию по разработке по, ему и то легче задание дали сравнить asp.net и php,описав плюсы и минусы. То что вы просите тянет на доклад на конференции.

Comment: А я думаю вопрос очень адекватен.

Comment: <p>При долговременной работе с одном средой программирования можно найти некоторые минусы, особенно при возможности сравнения с другими системами. Я не прошу одного человека описать все минусы и плюсы, дать полное сравнение и тп. Я прошу каждого желающего отписать хоть одно преимущество или недостаток указанных языков или одного из них. 
<p>Забыл добавить в старт-пост: Так как от результатов, написанных Вами в этом ответе, будет зависеть на что я потрачу огромное количество времени, то был бы  очень признателен, если ответы будут близкие к истине и желательно агрументированные. Спасибо.

Comment: <i>erlang,</i> если освоить значит написать мини-приложение с использованием всевозможных хелпов и при этом создать исключительно говнокод с тучей багов и нерациональностей, то Я могу и за неделю...но увы моих способностей не хватит на то, что бы за неделю выйти на достаточный уровень владения указанными средствами, хотя не исключаю что это вполне возможно для некоторых других людей.<br/> Так что Я от своих слов не отказываюсь, собираюсь убить на изучение большое количество времени и хотелось бы изучать лучший фреймворк из указанных, причем остальные меня не интересуют. Жду вашей помощи, спс.

Comment: АСПешникам больше платят )

Answer (score 9):

1. .NET (дотнет) платформа, вкупе с технологией доступа к данным ADO.NET - одно из лучших решений для разработки с точки зрения программиста. Очень удобна в разработке и отладке. Продуманная в смысле обновления отдельных элементов проекта. Огромная библиотека классов. Работа на ней более высокооплачиваемая (обычно раза в два). Лучшая из испробованных мной IDE - MS Visual Studio звточена как раз под .NET. Достаточно востребован.
   Но.
   Это дорогая в смысле развертывания платформа. Учитывая стоимость Windows-сервера и родного для ADO.NET MSSQL - очень дорогая. MONO (линуксовая альтернатива .NET) вряд ли когда догонит оригинал в плане производительности, укомплектованности и стабильности работы.
2. PHP. Что язык, что платформа, что инструменты разработки оставляют желать сильно лучшего. Если C# я мог бы назвать одним из лучших языков, то PHP - один из худших, начиная недоделанным ООП и заканчивая странными конструкциями.

Тем не менее. PHP + Linux + Apache + PostgerSQL - это вполне работоспособная и совершенно бесплатная платформа с неслабым комьюнити (что немаловажно). Не привожу в качестве альтернативного решения MySQL, так как не вижу в данной СУБД ни одного плюса, а минусов в ней просто море. Самый существенный плюс PHP - очень низкий порог вхождения в технологию. В разы ниже чем для .NET или Java. Соответственно, вы намного быстрее можете приступить к работе, если начинать с нуля. Весьма востребован на рынке.

1. PHP фреймворки.
    Zend, Codeigniter, Kohana, Yii и прочие производные MVC-паттерна. Разница между ними довольно относительная. Про Zend хорошего можно сказать только то, что в нем уйма всяких библиотек, значительно больше чем в остальных (но он очень громоздкий). Во всем прочем Zend ничем не лучше альтернатив. Лично я много работал с Kohana и немного меньше с прототипом коханы - CodeIgniter. Довольно неплохие решения, быстрое ядро, имеются все необходимые для решения большинства задач библиотеки, CI отличается большим упором в быстродействие, Kohana - большим удобством API. Все упомянутые фреймворки пользуются спросом. Zend и CI чаще других.
2. Java. Где-то между двумя выше рассмотренными категориями. По быстродействию сравним с .NET, по хроническому хаосу в библиотеках и решениях - с PHP (ибо бесплатен и вообще опенсорс). Что неудивительно, так как дотнет делался как конкурент джаве с учетом всех ошибок второй. Но если вам нужна бесплатная платформа и хорошее быстродействие, то других альтернатив просто нет. Главный минус Java - найти толковый хостинг, или настроить свой сервер, что несколько сложнее, чем в случае с PHP и даже .NET. Востребован наравне с .NET.
3. RoR (Ruby on Rails) - тоже как Джава похож на гибрид .NET и PHP, но наоборот. Здесь почти исключительная ситуация, когда в бесплатном решении мы имеем хорошо продуманный язык и богатую библиотеку классов. Active Records из RoR - это несбывшаяся мечта пхп-ешника. Недостатки: плохо с хостингом, медленный. По разным тестамм один из самых медленных интерпретаторов (местами даже медленнее PHP). Менее востребован.
4. Python. Подобно Руби и ПХП - скриптовый (а значит медленный в выполнении) язык. Есть несколько популярных фреймворков : Django, TurboGears, Pylons, Zope. Каждый имеет свой спектр задач, которые решает достаточно хорошо. Универсального пожалуй нет. Тут все так же хаотично как в PHP и Java. Востребован на равне с RoR.

Это то, как вопрос видится мне лично. Надеюсь, кому-то мое оформленное в текст мнение окажется полезным. Понимая принципиальную холиварность темы на положительную реакцию "гуру" не рассчитываю :)